# How can I enlarge text size of google bar chart and show x value on each bar?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-api, google-visualization, bar-chart

Good morning everyone,

I have a problem about the size of bar chart values. The x values goes like 0,5,10,15,20,23 five by five but I want it to be like 0,1,2,3 one by one.

Another issue is, I want y values to be shown on top of each bar. If 23th bar's value is 10 it must be shown on the top of 23th bar because people should easily see the chart values from the distant.

And my last question is I want to enlarge the size of x and y values of chart but I could only enlarge labels. I couldn't find the right option.

Oh almost I forgot, I have another problem about legend. If legend is on the right side, the chart is getting smaller but I can't move legend to top or bottom. Even in the code says legend bottom it shows on the right.

[image: Picture of Bar Chart]

my codes are here

```
 function drawPaLoChart() {
    var data = [['Hours', 'Label1', 'Label2']];



    for (var i=0; i<pageload.length;i++){
        data.push([pageload[i][0], pageload[i][1], pageload[i][2] ]);
    }

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);


    var options = {

     'fontSize': 30,

        chart: {

            'width': 600,

            title: 'Hourly Page Load Times',


        },

            legend: { position: 'bottom' },


            bar: { groupWidth: "100%" },
            backgroundColor: {fill: 'transparent'},
            chartArea: {
                backgroundColor: 'transparent'

            },
        'tooltipFontSize':22






    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('palochart'));

    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to add labels to the bar, you need to add an annotation column role to the data table.

however, you are using a *material* bar chart.

column roles, along with several other options, are not supported by *material* charts.
see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

*material* = `google.charts.Bar` -- `packages: ['bar']`

*classic* = `google.visualization.ColumnChart` -- `packages: ['corechart']`

---

using a *classic* chart, we can use a data view to add the annotation column role.
see following snippet...

```
function drawPaLoChart() {
  var data = [
    ['Hours', 'Label1', 'Label2']
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < pageload.length; i++) {
    data.push([pageload[i][0], pageload[i][1], pageload[i][2]]);
  }

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

  var options = {
    fontSize: 30,
    width: 600,
    title: 'Hourly Page Load Times',
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    bar: {
      groupWidth: "100%"
    },
    backgroundColor: {
      fill: 'transparent'
    },
    chartArea: {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    },
    tooltipFontSize: 22
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('palochart'));

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: 'stringify',
    sourceColumn: 1,
    role: 'annotation',
    type: 'string'
  }]);

  // use data view to draw chart
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```